# Meteor can't run gcloud on server side

Tags: meteor, reactjs, npm, memcpy, gcloud-node

I'm building a small application that allows you to upload files, store them in the cloud and analyze them with Google Cloud Vision API.

I got the uploading and storing working now, I use firebase for that, but when I try to run gcloud I run into some issues.

In the main.js file in server folder I run:

```
import gcloud from 'gcloud';
console.log('gcloud', gcloud);
```

But that causes an error in the terminal:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.

Unable to resolve some modules:

  "memcpy" in /C/Users/Zino/Documents/Meteor Projects/find-it/node_modules/bytebuffer/dist/ByteBufferNB.js
(os.windows.x86_32)

If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

  meteor npm install --save memcpy
```

My site does not load so I run:

```
meteor npm install --save memcpy
```

But then I get an error I'n can't find anything about in the internet:
[node error log](http://zino.hofmann.amsterdam/npm-debug.log)

I've been been trying to solve this issue for 2 days now, without luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like some problems with NPM package. You can try to use [micah:google-cloud](https://atmospherejs.com/micah/google-cloud). I'm using it on production and it works fine.

Comment: @Tdm when installing that package I get the error: No compatible binary build found found for this package.

Comment: Is it compatible with Meteor 1.3?

Comment: Yes it is. And I didn't have this problem. Which OS do you use?

Comment: I'm currently running Windows 10

Comment: That's the source of the problem. It is working fine on Linux or Mac OS.

Comment: Well, waiting for the Keynote from Monday ;)

Comment: Thanks @Tdm for linking my old wrapper package. As @Zino found out, this is no longer useful since Meteor started supporting direct import of NPM packages and moved from Node 0.10.x to LTS. I'm currently stuck trying to get `gcloud-node` to work with my Meteor 1.4 app on Ubuntu.

Comment: I get a `403 Forbidden` when following the [error log link](http://zino.hofmann.amsterdam/npm-debug.log) in the question.  Could you post the contents inline if its feasible or update the link?  Also, seems from some later comments that various environment conditions have changed like OS and possibly other dependency versions.  Could you updated those as well within the question to reflect the most current state of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, this was fixed by installing + importing specific sub-packages of google-cloud, rather than the `google-cloud` metapackage, which includes everything.

e.g.

```
$ npm install --save @google-cloud/datastore
$ npm install --save @google-cloud/storage

var config = {
  projectId: 'grape-spaceship-123',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
};

var datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')(config);
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')(config);
```

Comment: Google updated their packages, so currently this answer could be considered correct.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Windows being the culprit: The build fails at `'node-gyp configure build'`, which has a [build dependency](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) on Visual C++ Build Tools / Visual Studio 2015 and Python 2.7 on Windows. It can build on Windows, but is not as straightforward as building on a Unix-y system due to lack of a standard C++ toolchain. The [Microsoft Node.js Guidelines for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules), which make special mention of 'running into dreaded node-gyp issues', should have all the steps needed to get the build to work.

Comment: Yeah I read some GitHub pages about it. I recently bought a MacBook Pro, and still get the same error.

Comment: Interesting. To clarify, it's the same node-gyp build error you received when trying on Windows?